# kinit Password Expire Warning

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain, password, kinit

I've a Ubuntu desktop client joined to an Active Directory 2008 R2 domain.

I need to use "kinit" command on Linux to determine when a user password will expire. That's my way to go due to other scripts running on system so can't / don't want to change that approach.

However, as far as I saw, kinit returns password expire warning for 7 days or lower. Can I change this attitude? What makes kinit return the password expire warning message for 7 days or shorter timespan?

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the setting in Active Directory - it's set in Group Policy, in: *Interactive Logon: Prompt user to change password before expiration*.

So check with the AD administrator. It is possible to scope this policy to OUs, so if your account resides in a specific OU, it might be possible to set a longer warning there. It's *technically* possible, at least. There may be operational constraints.

Also, is the machine joined via `sssd`? It's worth reading this article to see if there's something in `sssd.conf` that might be overriding the value sent from AD. If it's not set in `sssd.conf` at all, it'll just be inheriting what AD is sending. https://access.redhat.com/articles/3027531

If the domain admin says it's set to 7 days and won't be changing, it's not clear whether you'd be able to configure `sssd.conf` to provide a longer warning interval - I doubt it could override AD in that way.

Alternatively, you could do an LDAP query on the AD user account and grab a property called `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` - the value there is ticks past the Windows epoch date.

To calculate the date on a Linux system, the Windows epoch date is 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z, which is 11644473600 seconds before the *nix epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). The Windows ticks are in 100 nanoseconds. So for a simple calculation:

```
$tickInterval = 10000000
$unixEpochDiff = 11644473600
# interval captured from msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
$ADPasswordExpiryTime = 132985454614249065 
$unixTime = ($userPasswordExpiryTime / $tickInterval) - $unixEpochDiff
```

At present, I have no way of testing an LDAP query from a Linux-based system to AD, but it could be worth a try if nothing else helps.